# Push tags/releases from fork to origin in git

Tags: git, github

I do development work on a fork of a GitHub repository. I can create annotated tags on any commit and push them as follows:

```
# cd to my fork
git tag -a c1.0.1 <commit-id> -m "my v1.0.1"
git push origin v1.0.1
```

However, these tags show up in the [Release/Tags](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/viewing-your-repositorys-releases-and-tags) page in the fork but not in origin.

I created a new Release and Tag on the latest code using the [manual method on GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-releases-in-a-repository), but I cannot use that with old commits. Maybe I can clone the origin and push tags from there, as I should have all privileges, but I might forget to do that in future releases.

How to push a tag on my fork to origin so that it appears in the releaases/tags page of origin?

Answer (score 0):

From my fork, which has the upstream set up as follows:

```
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/<myusername>/somerepo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/<myusername>/somerepo.git (push)
upstream    https://github.com/<origin>/somerepo.git (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/<origin>/somerepo.git (push)
```

I could simply do:

`git push --tags upstream`